# Form in menu ux design query

Tags: website-design, design, menu

So I have a use case where we have a button that is to trigger the "reassign" flow

this obviously needs a list of people to reassign to (1 or many)

I have a multiselect typeahead creating the list. This is consistent with the rest of the UI/UX design.

I am however not happy with the button creating a dropdown menu, and have the select +2 buttons (a short cut for "assign to me" and "assign")

I do not want a modal. Any other thoughts of how to make this better both UX and UI

Previous:

[image]

ATTEMPT 1:

[image]

Comment: Do you need the "assign" button or could it be part of the select interface? Something like a checkmark that appears only when a username is matched and sits inside the element would work. Also, I assume users are going to be interacting with the keyboard to search users so binding the enter key to "complete" the action would be expected. I think that the more this LOOKS like a traditional input form, the more you'll struggle with it.

Comment: it's a multi-select so can have lots of users, and we want to avoid setting assignees everytime one is selected (as the logs would fill up if nothing else) hence the assign button...

Comment: In that case, are there checkboxes (or some other selection technique) in the type-ahead list? I'm mostly responding to the size and placement of that button. I think it could appear inline with the list and be quite a bit smaller. How familiar are users with this list and how frequently is "assign to me" the needed option? If those are both high, you could remove the "assign to me" button and default the list item to "me" with my name selected. This removes the multiple interaction paradigms.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think the elements or interactions are really the problems here. In my opinion, the visual design is causing the catch. Elements don't have any spacing around them so it means they feel detached from the "menu" trigger.

I would suggest making the background obviously unique and when "open" it should wrap around the trigger element AND expand with the content. Start with just the assign to me button and the search field then expand the background WITH the search field when it expands. I would guess the part that's bugging you is that it feels like two select lists on top of each other. Building a container that responds to the other elements would fix that.

[image]

Comment: thank's for this. I have yet to put in the "assign to me" button but have updated original posst to include what I now have. thoughts/opinions very welcome